# Is there a special android build for AT&T Samsung Galaxy?  PhoneStateListner not working.

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an app that implements a PhoneStateListner.  The code works on all phones except the AT&T Samsung Galaxy.  Is there a special build for that phone?  Does anyone know of a way, besides buying a phone, to test this build on an emulator?

This may be indicative of android where the carriers can create their own build and distribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer after testing:

The App I built uses a PhoneStateListener to listen for incoming calls and perform an action.

It was running on most devices until I changed the Project Build Target from Android 1.5 to Google API's 2.2.  I changed the Build Target to implement Google Maps. No code had changed in the PhoneStateListener.

On the Galaxy phones users were reporting that the application was not running anymore.  I reverted just the Project Build Target, with the same code and the application now works on Galaxy.

So this points to a bit of fragmentation.  Got it solved so now the application works like a charm.

Comment: i am facing the same kind of issue and my default build target is set Android 4.0 so it should be working fine right?